# How do I make Tor only give me one alternate ip address?

Tags: configuration, anonymity, ip-address

Awhile ago, I had installed the Tor Browser as a way to evade an IP ban on a game I play. The Tor Browser was working quite well, until one of the IP addresses used was also IP banned. So, my question is, is there a way to make the Tor browser only use one alternate IP address, and potentially have the IP Address set in only one country, to reduce the chances of this occuring again?

If this isn't possible, or incredibly difficult to do, is there a way to change the location of my alternate IPs to only be positioned in a single location? (Preferably an uncommon location, such as Japan)

Comment: try the magic word 'country' in search bar.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows, it might work on other a different os too, up towards the left there's a green onion. Click on it and it will show your circuit on the right. The last one before it says internet is where your base ip address is coming from. If you want to change the ip click on 'New Tor Circuit for this Site' and It can change it to something else. (This might make you restart the browser. [image: Picture of what I'm talking about.]